# Azure Wordpress PHP Worker Role Terminates soon after start when following the azure sdk for php wordpress scaffold

Tags: php, wordpress, azure

I'm trying to install Wordpress on Azure while using the PHP-Wordpress scaffold from interoperability bridges (link below):

http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/how-to-deploy-wordpress-using-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php-wordpress-scaffold

I'm having trouble deploying Wordpress locally.

The PhpOnAzure  Web role is getting destroyed immediately after it starts running and leaves the following log entries in the Azure Compute Emulator:

[Diagnostics]: UpdateState(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration, )[Diagnostics]: Acquired mutex[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\alving\AppData\Local\dftmp\s0\deployment(1)\res\deployment(1).PhpOnAzure.WebRole.0\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor[Diagnostics] Information: C:\temp\WordPress.cspkg\roles\WebRole\diagnostics\x64\monitor\MonAgentHost.exe -LocalPath "C:\Users\alving\AppData\Local\dftmp\s0\deployment(1)\res\deployment(1).PhpOnAzure.WebRole.0\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor" -StaticConfigFile "C:\Users\alving\AppData\Local\dftmp\s0\deployment(1)\res\deployment(1).PhpOnAzure.WebRole.0\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\mastaticconfig.xml" -ConfigFile "C:\Users\alving\AppData\Local\dftmp\s0\deployment(1)\res\deployment(1).PhpOnAzure.WebRole.0\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\maconfig.xml" -ShutDownEvent WADDM-ShutDown-0d41386971f44ea68ee4b142bdcbc572 -InitializedEvent WADM-StartUp-0d41386971f44ea68ee4b142bdcbc572 -parent 6000 -events[Diagnostics]: Creating config channel server[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when WADDM-ShutDown-0d41386971f44ea68ee4b142bdcbc572 is signaled.[MonAgentHost] Output: Will signal WADM-StartUp-0d41386971f44ea68ee4b142bdcbc572 after the agent is initialized.[MonAgentHost] Output: Registered as an event consumer.[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when parent process 6000 exits.[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Started[Diagnostics]: Starting configuration channel polling[fabric] Role state Created[fabric] Role state Suspended[fabric] Role state Busy[fabric] Role state Stopping[fabric] Role state Stopped[fabric] Role state Aborted[fabric] Role state Teardown[fabric] Role state Destroyed[Diagnostics]: UpdateState(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration, )

Any help figuring this out is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with your diagnostics connection string in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file. It should look similar to the following when doing local development:

If you are still having issues download the latest WordPress scaffold. Many issues have been resolved